# Django get choice display on using .values

Tags: django, model, choicefield

For a `Model` with field `type`, is there any way to get the choice display value on using `Model.objects.values()` ? I tried `Model.objects.values('get_type_display')` but it doesn't work.

Comment: No. Don't use values.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that. `values` is a built in django queryset method which is used to get dictionaries of data instead of model instances you can read more about it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values).

The conventional (and proper) way of attaching choices with model for a field is using static variable like this.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    TYPE_CHOICES = (
        # (<DB VALUE>, <DISPLAY_VALUE>)
        ('a', 'Choice A'),
        ('b', 'Choice B'),
    )

    type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=TYPE_CHOICES)
```

You can access choices for type field outside model like this.

```
MyModel.TYPE_CHOICES
```

Answer (score 2):

Where I do call `.values` of choice fields into my queryset I deal with this in the following way:

Assume the following model

```
from enum import Enum

class TypeChoice(Enum):
    a = 'class A'
    b = 'class B'

class MyModel(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=[(tag.name,tag.value) for tag in TypeChoice])
```

Using the query `my_qset = MyModel.objects.values('type')` the display values are available as:

```
for item in my_qset:
     print(TypeChoice[item].value)
```

To deal with this in my templates I write a custom template filter, say `type_display`:

```
from django import template
import TypeChoice
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def type_display(var):
    return TypeChoice[var].value
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar need and unfortunately you can't do so with only `values`; however, you can do something similar with some crafty annotations and django's custom enums (`IntegerChoices`/`TextChoices`) classes.

I created this from another SO question but I can't remember where I got the inspiration from. Basically, you can pass in the corresponding model or the choices you'd like to map back to labels via annotations on the queryset.

```py
class ChoicesLabelCase(Case):
    def __init__(self, field: str, model: Model = None, choices: list = None, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        if choices is None and model is None:
            raise ValueError("Either a model or a choices parameter must be provided.")
        elif choices is None:
            choices = model._meta.get_field(field).flatchoices

        cases_list = [When(**{field: val, "then": Value(label)}) for (val, label) in choices]
        super(ChoicesLabelCase, self).__init__(*cases_list, output_field=CharField(), *args, **kwargs)
```

As an example take this model:

```py
class FruitType(models.IntegerChoices):
    APPLE = 1, 'Apple'
    BANANA = 2, 'Banana'
    ORANGE = 3, "Orange"

class Fruit(models.Model):
    type = models.IntegerField(choices=FruitType.choices)
```

You can annotate the labels like so:

```py
>>> Fruit.objects.all().annotate(
    type_label=ChoicesLabelCase('type', FruitType)
).values("type", "type_label")

[
    {'type': 1, 'type_label': 'Apple'}, 
    {'type': 2, 'type_label': 'Banana'}, 
    ...
]
```

Comment: This is just exactly the answer @msf, your example has an inverted arguments but, is easy to follow, thank you!

Comment: Oops thanks for the note, I just fixed it but I'm glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

This code example maybee help you:

```
 alertsfilter = list(Alerte.objects.filter(viewed__isnull=False).values(
    'id', 
    'type', 
    'created_at', 
    'viewed',
    'sent', 
    'agent_id', 
    'geofence_id', 
    'objet__id', 
    'objet__nom',
    'objet__marker',
    'geofence__id'))

for alert in alertsfilter:
    # alert_type = alert['type']
    alert['type'] = Alerte.objects.get(pk=alert['id']).get_type_display()
```